# Find an equation of the tangent plane to the given function at the given point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$z = \sin(xy)$ at the point $(x,y) = (2,3\pi /4)$

Work I have done so far:

Partial derivatives:

$$f_x(x,y) = \cos(xy)y \implies f_x\left(2,\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{3\pi}{4}\cos\frac{6\pi}{4}\\
f_y(x,y) = \cos(xy)x \implies f_y\left(2,\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) = 2\cos\frac{6\pi}{4}\\
z-0 = \frac{3\pi}{4}\cos\frac{6\pi}{4}\left(x-2\right)+2\cos\frac{6\pi}{4}\left(x-\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$$

answer: [link to incorrect answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weQcc.png)

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your questions.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please check that I haven't messed anything up when I reformatted your question.  What exactly is your question?  Do you think this answer is wrong?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

On the left-hand side, you should not have $z-0,$ but $z-f(2,3\pi /4).$  Also, $\cos\frac{6\pi}{4} = \cos\frac{3\pi}{2} = 0,$ so you can make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $(1,0,f_x(x_0,y_0))$ and $(0,1,f_y(x_0,y_0))$ are tangent to the surface (in the given point ).
Their cross product $(-f_x,-f_y,1)$ will be normal to the surface and thus to tangent plane.
Now build the equation of a plane, passing through the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and having the cross product as the normal vector.